# Using a S3 method from an unloaded R package

Tags: r, lubridate

Let's look at the example of the method `months` for type `numeric` from the lubridate package.
When loading the package, everything works as expected:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
months(3)
#> [1] "3m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

However, I can't access the method when the package is not loaded.

```r
lubridate::months(3)
#> Error: 'months' is not an exported object from 'namespace:lubridate'
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I don't want to call the function with `:::` as this is bad practice. Assuming I don't want to load the package, what can I do?

Comment: `months` is from `base`.

Comment: @markus But the base package does not have a `months()` method for numeric; `months.numeric()` is indeed provided by `lubridate`. Try, in a fresh R session, `months(3)`; you'll get `Error in UseMethod("months") : no applicable method for 'months' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Comment: @duckmayr That's a good point. Wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Why do you not want to load the package?

Comment: @ Hugh because the scripts are large and I don't want namespace cluttering, so I dediced to only load a handful packages. Maybe time to turn this into a package anyways. Hope the problem does not persist though.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way it works but you could hide the ::: in a function definition so your main code can just use `months`.

```
months.numeric <- lubridate:::months.numeric

months(3)
## [1] "3m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [G. Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53031176/8386140) is to use `getFromNamespace()`:

```
months.numeric <- getFromNamespace("months.numeric", "lubridate")
months(3)
# [1] "3m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```